# javascript основы

Tags: javascript

В React JS, если правильно помню, был "prop" для не повторения таких блоков с одинаковой структурой, но с разными текстами... Как это написать на чистом JS?

```
<div>
     <span class="name">John Smith</span>
     <span class="age">35</span>
     <span class="city">London</span>
</div>
<div>
     <span class="name">Monica Douson</span>
     <span class="age">30</span>
     <span class="city">New York</span>
</div>
```

Comment: при помощи цикла

Comment: Можете примером показать для этого кода? Прошу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

всё же помогу)

**убедительная просьба, чтобы не ловить минусы за вопрос — выкладывайте ваши попытки решить задачу**

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

const array = [
  {
    name: 'John Smith',
    age: 35,
    location: 'London'
  },
  {
    name: 'Monica Douson',
    age: 30,
    location: 'New York'
  }
];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const template = `
    <span class="name">${array[i].name}</span>
    <span class="age">${array[i].age}</span>
    <span class="city">${array[i].location}</span>
  `;

  const node = document.createElement('div');

  node.innerHTML = template;

  container.appendChild(node);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли!